# Combine two Salesforce SOQL Query

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-communities

I am using two SOQL query in Salesforce.

First Query: Select Id, FirstName, LastName from User where Id='00000ADFEDSFSRTGDR'
Second Query: Select IsFrozen from UserLogin where UserId='00000ADFEDSFSRTGDR'

Can we combine these two query into a single query. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you use "describe" calls on `User` or `UserLogin` you'll see they are linked but there's no "relationshipName" field in the describe's result. That's what's used to link, bit like table alias in normal database.

```
// No going "up"
System.debug(UserLogin.UserId.getDescribe().getRelationshipName());

// And no going "down" either
for(Schema.ChildRelationship cr : User.SObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()){
    if(cr.getChildSObject() == UserLogin.sObjectType && cr.getField() == UserLogin.UserId){
        System.debug(cr);
        System.debug(cr.getRelationshipName());
    }
}
```

So you can do

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
    (SELECT PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignments)
FROM User
```

because `PermissionSetAssignment.AssigneeId` has relationshipName. But not

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
    (SELECT IsFrozen FROM UserLogin)
FROM User
```

Going "up" doesn't work either. `SELECT Account.Name FROM Contact` works OK but `SELECT IsFrozen, User.Name FROM UserLogin` doesn't. Again - because there's no `relationshipName` in the describe results.

You'll have to query separately and link them them in code as `Map<Id, User>` for example.